# Component fetching from endpoint

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I would like to check if there's anyone that could show a implementation of a component that is included from a route page (+page.svelte) where the component itself is responsible for fetching the data and handling that trough an endpoint specific to that component.

Previously I have included the data into the component and fetched it in parent component but I guess it must be possible for the component itself to fetch the data.

The aim is for example to have implementation inside the component itself like

```html
<Mycomponent>
```

instead of

```html
<Mycomponent {myArray}>
```

I we take this code snippet as an example. This is similar to what I do but I need to use POST method API fetch call.

```js
<script lang="ts">

  async function getDataFromAPI() {
    const body = {
        action: 'search',
    };
    const res = await fetch('https://externalAPI.com', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    });
    const values = await res.json();

    return values;
  }
  
  let promise = getDataFromAPI();

</script>
  
{#await promise }
    <p>...waiting</p>
{:then data}
    <p>{data.length} my data </p>
{:catch error}
    <p style="color: red">{error.message}</p>
{/await}
```

The problem seems to be that in my case data is undefined even if when I console.log(values) in this case there's the correct data information.
So I end up in the catch error case and get error 'Failed to fetch'.

Comment: What is stopping you? Should just be a `fetch` call away.

Comment: @H.B.
Im aware of that but the issue is that the fetch is using POST as method which is something I can't change.

Comment: Why? The default is `GET` and you can set it arbitrarily.

Comment: I added some more info to the issue.. maybe it's easier to tell what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I solved it with doing as before but not using any endpoint.. running the fetch POST call inside the +page.server.js file directly.. I think the latest SvelteKit changes made it a bit confusing since my old code was based on the time before the big routing changes happened.

Comment: If you solved it, add your own answer and accept it, or delete the question, if you think it is not helpful to anyone else.

Comment: did you figure out?

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible.  Basically, two ways to go about it.  First is to do the fetch (or call a function imported from somewhere else that does the fetch) in the script tag of the +page.svelte file you want to use it in, and then refer to the variable you stored the fetched data in within the template.

The other way to do it moves the fetch into a separate file. I'm not sure of the pros and cons of this, as I'm still fairly new to svelte myself.

You want to create a +page.js/+page.ts file with an exported load function that fetches the needed data and returns the data in an object.

Then, in your +page.svelte file, you export a variable named data.  The data variable will contain the object that your load function returned.

When I get the chance, I'll hack up a quick demonstration and include the code here.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).